# How to separate address into multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked through this site and can't find the correct answer.

I have a field called ADDRLINE1 that holds the Contact address.  The address is entered into the application like this.

```
 7710 Computer Ave.
 Ste. 103
 Edina, MN 55435
```

There is a carriage return after each line.  Sometimes there is a suite # and sometimes not.

I need to separate this address into different columns.

```
   Addr1               Addr2         Addr3    City    State   ZipCode
7710 Computer Ave.    Ste. 103        NULL    Edina    MN      55435
```

How do I do this?  I've seen a few examples but none are what I'm  looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show what you've tried?  What examples that didn't work for you were?  Why didn't those examples work?

Comment: If you remove address 3, then you can split the lines on a carriage return, then split the third line by spaces.

Comment: This is one of those jobs that's harder than it looks.  See here. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22339/open-source-address-correction-parser-with-fuzzy-matching

Comment: Why do people try to do this with SQL? The application should have the logic that splits the string and sends the appropriate data to the appropriate field. Languages like PHP, C# and PERL are really good at this.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  The data is a mess in the application (Prolaw). I have no idea why they would put the address as just one address line in the database. We're going to have to clean the data before we can continue.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleanest and most efficient way, and I'm sure there is most likely a much better and faster way to do this, but this should get you by until someone else answers with a better solution:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( ADDRLINE1 VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT  INTO @tbl
    SELECT  '7710 Computer Ave' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Ste. 103' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'suite #123' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Edina, MN 55435'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '7710 Computer Ave' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Ste. 103' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Edina, MN 55435'

SELECT  SUBSTRING([ADDRLINE1], 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), [ADDRLINE1]) - 1) AS Addr1 ,
    SUBSTRING([ADDRLINE1], CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), [ADDRLINE1]) + 2, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), REPLACE([ADDRLINE1], SUBSTRING([ADDRLINE1], 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), [ADDRLINE1]) + 1), '')) - 1) AS Addr2 ,
    CASE WHEN (LEN([ADDRLINE1]) - LEN(REPLACE([ADDRLINE1],CHAR(13),''))) = 3
        THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([ADDRLINE1],REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([ADDRLINE1]),1,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),REVERSE([ADDRLINE1])))),'')),
                               1,
                               CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),REVERSE(REPLACE([ADDRLINE1],REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([ADDRLINE1]),1,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),REVERSE([ADDRLINE1])))),'')))-2)) ELSE NULL END AS Addr3 ,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([ADDRLINE1]), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE([ADDRLINE1])) + 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), REVERSE([ADDRLINE1])) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE([ADDRLINE1])) - 1)) AS City ,
    SUBSTRING([ADDRLINE1], CHARINDEX(',', [ADDRLINE1]) + 2, 2) AS [State] ,
    SUBSTRING([ADDRLINE1], CHARINDEX(',', [ADDRLINE1]) + 5, 5) AS ZipCode 
FROM    @tbl
```

Output:

```
Addr1               Addr2       Addr3       City    State   ZipCode
7710 Computer Ave   Ste. 103    suite #123  Edina   MN      55435
7710 Computer Ave   Ste. 103    NULL        Edina   MN      55435
```

NOTE: The State and Zipcode columns are based on the assumption that the only comma in the value will be after the City. If that isn't a valid assumption I can make a few edits.

Comment: Thank you!  This got me very close but a lot of our addresses are incomplete so it kept failing when trying to extract the City because sometimes the zip wasn't there or the State was missing. We are going to have to start cleaning up the addresses before I can continue on this project.

Comment: Let me know if I can be of anymore help!